# Track option in select based on a specific property

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-options

I am diving directly on my problem:

On controller:

```
$scope.code = 1
$scope.codes [
  {
    "1":"Accepted"
    "0":"Rejected"
  }
```

On view:

```
<select ng-model="code" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in codes track by key"></select>
```

Is there any way to have "Accepted" selected on my view ? I know that the `$scope.code` is not an object but I want to assign it the value passed by selected option (key).

For anyone who would like to reproduce my problem, I got a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Z9PsFOUzTtdXx3nDRyk?p=preview) made.

Comment: You want "Accepted" to be default selected?

Comment: I want an option to be selected based on the `$scope.code`. In this example "Accepted" should be selected because is the value of key: 1 which is equal to my `$scope.code` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to do minor changes:
Remove the **track by** statement like this:
`<select ng-model="myVal" ng-options="key as val for (key,val) in data"></select>`
And in **$scope.myVal** set the value as **string** because you are assigning an integer.
And that should work.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was THAT sensitive. Thanks mate !